# Prompt won't stop at getline to store name to a variable

Tags: c++

Here is a small program to request and print some information. The problem point is storing name which may include spaces. My problem is that when reaches `Enter your name` it quickly moves to `Enter your total marks` without giving user an option to enter the name. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class StudentInformation {
protected:
    int studentID;
    string studentName;
    int totalMarks;
public:
    void input() {
        cout << "Enter your student id number: ";
        cin >> studentID;

        cout << "Enter your name: ";
        getline(cin, studentName);

        cout << "Enter your total marks";
        cin >> totalMarks;
    }

    void show() {
        cout << "Student ID: " << studentID << endl;
        cout << "Student Name: " << studentName << endl;
        cout << "Total Marks: " << totalMarks << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    StudentInformation stdinfo;

    stdinfo.input();
    stdinfo.show();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: For a thorough explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Answer (score 3):

Mixing use of `cin >>` with `getline` leads to problems.

- `cin >> studentID` leaves the newline in the stream.
- `getline` sees this straight away, so doesn't wait for new input.

I prefer using `getline` to read from the actual stream, and then using a `stringstream` for formatted extraction.

Or use [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) before `getline`:

```
std::cin >> ...; // leaves trailing whitespace and newline
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // eat next newline
std::getline(std::cin, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use  `cin.getline(studentName, size)`